# Añadir google maps a un carview con firebase

Tags: android

Buenos días, estoy haciendo una app en la cual obtengo una serie de items a través de Firebase utilizando un RecyclerView. Cuando hago click a cualquier de ese item lo que quiero es mostrar en un CardView los datos; nombre,dirección, teléfono etc y en otro Card quiero mostrar  google maps con el marcador de la dirección de ese item en el mapa.Los datos nombre, dirección, teléfono etc del primer Cardview si que consigo mostralos pero el mapa no. Si añado los datos para poder mostrar un mapa sencillo sin marcador ni nada por el estilo se cierra la aplciacion

public class BarItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mapa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bar_item);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

}
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mapa = googleMap;
    }

Y este es el código del archivo xml

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                map:liteMode="true"/>

           </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

He encontrado buscando por internet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828996/multiple-google-maps-lite-in-firebaserecycler

Como yo estoy también utilizando un FirebaseRecyclerAdapter lo he probado y tambien se me cierra la aplicación. En el logCat no veo el error.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tienes un error al buscar la referencia del mapa:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Ahí estas buscando un elemento tipo [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) pero en tu XML tienes declarado un [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

Al usar `MapView`, tienes que hacer varias cosas manuales como llamar los métodos del `lifecycle` cuando se debe, ejemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
 // Esta es la forma que debes usar para obtener un obj MapView
 mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);

 mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 // Asi obtienes el mapa
 googleMap = mapView.getMap()

...
}

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
```

Leyendo tu pregunta, siento que lo que tratas de implementar es un lista con detalles del "producto", osea que el usuario ve una lista y si clickea un elemento se abre otra ventana mostrando los detalles del elemento.

Si es así, yo creo que puedes implementar un `MapFragment`:

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Ya que este elemento maneja el `Lifecycle` por ti y en tu código Java ya tienes implementada la forma de obtener la referencia.

Si eso no es lo que quieres y lo que quieres hacer es mostrar una lista que en cada elemento tenga un mapa, definitivamente `MapView` es el indicado.

Saludos, espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por contestar pero trozo de código no funciona. El método getMap() esta deprecated sea sustituido por getMapAsync(). Declaro una variable view para poder llamar a findViewById(R.id.map) pero sigue dando error. Lo he probado en el viewHolder el mismo error. Seguiré intentando

Comment: @JoseBanyeres ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: Era como comente, que se cerraba la aplicación y era porque se me había olvidado quitar las líneas del MapFragment y como tu bien comentas necesito el MapView. Siguiendo este ejemplo https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/RawMapViewDemoActivity.java  si que me aparece el mapa pero en toda la Activity y yo lo que estoy buscando es que salga en el CardView. Por los ejemplos que estoy viendo he de hacerlo a través del Adapter o el ViewHolder y eso se que no se como hacerlo. Seguiré buscando Gracias